# Change div location based on page location

Tags: lightning-web-components

I have the following lwc component:

[image]

There are two sections in this component: "license details" and "notes".

I want to be able to move the side panel(marked in red) as i scroll through the page.

"License details" is located in the center of the page, so until i scroll to it, i don't see the side panel. When i get to height of the bottom of the side panel, i want it to move with my scroll, until it reaches the bottom of the section "license details", right before "notes".

How can i do this? i currently added `<div style="position: fixed; width: 400px; height: 320px;">` but it doesn't work.

```
<lightning-accordion-section name="secondSection" label={secondSectionLabel}>
    <lightning-layout vertical-align="start" >
        <lightning-layout-item size="9" class="slds-p-bottom_small slds-p-top_small slds-p-left_none slds-p-right_medium slds-border_right">
            <lightning-layout>
                <lightning-layout-item>
                    <div class="slds-text-heading_medium">Header</div>
                </lightning-layout-item>
                <lightning-layout-item alignment-bump="left">
                        <template if:false={sidePanel_EDIT}>
                            <lightning-button label="Add Items" class="slds-m-left_xx-small"></lightning-button>
                        </template>
                        <template if:true={sidePanel_EDIT}>
                            <lightning-button label="Save" class="slds-m-left_xx-small" onclick={handleSave} variant="brand" disabled={saveDisabled}></lightning-button>
                        </template>
                        <lightning-button label={editButtonLabel} class="slds-m-left_xx-small" onclick={handleEdit}></lightning-button>
                </lightning-layout-item> 
            </lightning-layout>

            <div class="slds-p-top_small">
                <c-custom-datatable key-field="Id" 
                                    data={generalDetailsLicenseItemsDisplay} 
                                    columns={generalDetailsColumns} 
                                    sorted-by={generalDetailsSortBy} 
                                    sorted-direction={generalDetailsSortDirection} 
                                    onsort={handleGeneralDetailsSortdata} 
                                    onrowaction={handleRowAction} 
                                    class="customDataTable" 
                                    hide-checkbox-column={hideCheckboxColumn}
                                    selected-rows={generalDetailsRows}
                                    onrowselection={getSelectedGeneralDetailsRows}
                                    >
                </c-custom-datatable>
            </div>

            <div class="slds-text-heading_medium slds-p-bottom_small">Products</div>
            <c-custom-datatable key-field="Id" 
                                class="customDataTable" 
                                data={licenseItemsDisplay} 
                                columns={productsColumns} 
                                onrowaction={handleRowAction} 
                                sorted-by={licenseItemSortBy} 
                                sorted-direction={licenseItemSortDirection} 
                                onsort={handlelicenseItemSortdata} 
                                hide-checkbox-column={hideCheckboxColumn}
                                selected-rows={productsRows}
                                onrowselection={getSelectedProductsRows}
                                >
            </c-custom-datatable>
            <br/>
        </lightning-layout-item> 
        <lightning-layout-item size="3" class="slds-p-bottom_small slds-p-top_small slds-p-right_none slds-p-left_medium">
            <div style="position: fixed; width: 400px; height: 320px;">
                SIDE PANEL
            </div>
        </lightning-layout-item>
    </lightning-layout>
</lightning-accordion-section>
<lightning-accordion-section name="thirdSection" label={thirdSectionLabel}>
    <lightning-record-view-form record-id={recordId} object-api-name="License__c">
        NEXT SECTION
    </lightning-record-view-form>
</lightning-accordion-section>
```

Comment: you want the side panel to be fixed  and dont move with scroll?

Comment: I want it to move with the scroll until it arrives to the next section

Answer (score 0):

if this is what you want https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/playground/wszCRUW1V/1/edit

if you expand the first section the right div will move with you until section end

you cn put following css

```
.test{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    top: 90px
    z-index: 99;
    position: -webkit-sticky;
    position: sticky;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 793px) {
    .test{
      top:141px !important;
    }
  }
```

[image]

Comment: It starts scrolling only when i reach the top of the page, not the top of the page layout (below the name of the record)

Comment: you can try setting top with different value also change the z-index i have edited the answer; @DanaGriff

Comment: it works in playground, but won't work in a page layout. can you try this in your org? @User6670

Comment: @DanaGriff i have added a gif is this how you want

Comment: it doesn't work in my org, on a record page.